# spurious push and unchanged pass error from wallet

Tags: java, ios, wallet

In my application, I get a lot of these errors.

> Error REST из apple wallet [2019-07-19 10:51:29 +0300] Web service
>   error for myOwnPassTypeIdentifier (https://webServiceURL): Device
>   received spurious push. Request for passesUpdatedSince
>   '30657301263000' returned no serial numbers. (Device = ....)

And also

> Error REST из apple wallet [2019-07-19 12:43:33 +0300] Web service
>   error for myOwnPassTypeIdentifier (https://webServiceURL): Server
>   ignored the 'if-modified-since' header (Fri, 19 Jul 2019 09:43:14 GMT)
>   and returned the full unchanged pass data for serial number
>   '2222000174317170'.

How can I avoid them, hot to heal ? )

Comment: You sent a push, presumably because you had more content.  But when the device asked for the serial of the new content, you didn't send a response.

Comment: For the second error, if the content has not changed but the device is requesting the pass, you should send a 304 response.  You can test this by manually refreshing the pass.

Comment: What do you mean about `more content`? In the card/pass is changed Points, for example, it was 20 000 points and after the client had bought something he got more points and it became 20 500 points. I suppose, after that, our server would send a push to the client.

Comment: @PassKit And while server generates pass this new Points sets into pass and sends to the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For preventing that error I had to send a correct date as `last modified` tag with Response in `/passes/{passTypeIdentifier}/{serialNumber}` method with prepared Pass and also in `/devices/{deviceLibraryIdentifier}/registrations/{passTypeIdentifier}` with corrected SerialNumbers

I got a correct date from DB and push it to Response. So, any modification,firstly updated DB, then I send push to APNs and got Request to update pass, where I had `last modified` from the previous Request which I compare with actual date in my DB.